# How to create a toolbar on top of navigation drawer(Android/kotlin)

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-toolbar, navigation-drawer

I want to have a toolbar on top of navigation drawer like this
[image]

Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and my app_bar_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When i'm trying to create a toolbar in the activity_main.xml nothing happens...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: @AlexKolydas check upadated answer

Comment: Now it shows me this :/
[link](https://ibb.co/cVFeoK)
[link](https://ibb.co/g0GVvz)

Comment: Almost perfect!!It is more darker (just as the background)
[link](https://ibb.co/emWc8K)

also do you know maybe how to change the text next to <- 
Mine writes "today" and i want to write "weather".It's ok if you don't know i'm just asking!

Comment: @AlexKolydas use this `drawer.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));`

Comment: @AlexKolydas Which text you want to change?

Comment: This is my main activity [link](https://ibb.co/cVFeoK)
and this is when i press the drawer [link](https://ibb.co/emWc8K)
i want the "today" text to change into "weather"
it's ok if you don't know my other problem was solved and thank you so much!

Comment: Sure thing my friend!Thanks again!